# Eevee - problem with lighting, mesh is darker in some places

Tags: lighting, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to set up a studio lighting scene for my objects renders but something weird is happening and I can't figure out why.

I'm working with Eevee and looks like to top part of my mesh is lit from the back instead of the front.

[image]

From the back, you can see the right lighting.

[image]

I looked up if it wasn't due to the faces orientation/normals but everything seems fine.

[image]

Any ideas ?

EDIT : [Here's my scene](https://we.tl/t-HvlBNdXpdl)

Comment: Could be flipped normals. Go into edit mode and press SHIFT+N.

Comment: Already tried fixing the normals, everything is facing the right way :/

Comment: Unchecking the toggle `Context (tab) > Normals > Auto Smooth` worked for me.